# SQL Server 2022 setup silently closes with no clue

Tags: setup, sql-server-2022

When trying to install SQL Server 2022 from iso, I can't get setup wizard doing a single (visible) action when I click the "New SQL Server standalone installation" link.

Everything seems being blocked at landingPage.exe startup. All I can get from `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\160\Setup Bootstrap\Log` is the following:

```
    (01) 2022-12-14 08:38:52 Slp: Completed Action: ExecuteBootstrapAfterExtensionsLoaded, returned True
    (01) 2022-12-14 08:38:52 Slp: ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (01) 2022-12-14 08:38:52 Slp: Running Action: LandingPage
    (01) 2022-12-14 08:38:52 Slp: Landing page action
    (01) 2022-12-14 08:38:52 Slp: Starting Landing Page: Path = D:\x64\LandingPage.exe, Arguments =  /ENU /MEDIASOURCE="D:\\"
```

LandingPage summary is the following:

```
    Overall summary:
      Final result:                  Passed
      Exit code (Decimal):           0
      Start time:                    2022-12-14 08:38:50
      End time:                      2022-12-14 08:48:19
      Requested action:              LandingPage
    
    Machine Properties:
      Machine name:                  XXXXXXXXXX
      Machine processor count:       8
      OS version:                    Microsoft Windows 10 Entreprise (10.0.19044)
      OS service pack:               
      OS region:                     United States
      OS language:                   français (France)
      OS architecture:               x64
      Process architecture:          64 Bit
      OS clustered:                  No
    
    Package properties:
      Description:                   Microsoft SQL Server 2022 
      ProductName:                   SQL Server 2022
      Type:                          RTM
      Version:                       16
      SPLevel:                       0
      Installation location:         D:\x64\setup\
      Installation edition:          
    
    Notice: Please read Microsoft SQL Server Software License Terms at aka.ms/useterms.
    
    User Input Settings:
      ACTION:                        LandingPage
      CONFIGURATIONFILE:             
      ENU:                           true
      HELP:                          false
      IACKNOWLEDGEENTCALLIMITS:      false
      INDICATEPROGRESS:              false
      QUIET:                         false
      QUIETSIMPLE:                   false
      SUPPRESSPAIDEDITIONNOTICE:     false
      SUPPRESSPRIVACYSTATEMENTNOTICE: false
      UIMODE:                        Normal
    
      Configuration file:            C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\160\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20221214_083850\ConfigurationFile.ini
    
    Rules with failures or warnings:
    
    Rules report file:               The rule result report file is not available.
```

I previously installed SQL Server 2022 CTP2 on the same machine, but I chose to remove all the stuff prior to set the RTM version up, and all went fine at the time :/

What am I supposed to do to make it installed?
Thanks,

Comment: Any relevant errors in the Windows Event Log? Does the path `D:\x64\LandingPage.exe` exist?

Comment: Nothing relevant. Yes, the path exists, it is mapped to accurate folder of mounted ISO. The only thing I am sure of is that this LandingPage.exe process looks like hanged, waiting for something it is not complaining lacking of 

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I had the same issue when trying to upgrade SQL2014. Never been able to fix it anyway, using Procmon tool or whatever log parsing

Copied the mounted-ISO install stuff to any hard-drive folder in %temp% made the setup seamlessly achieved ‍♂️

*P.S: This behaviour never had been during first install, only after uninstall+reinstall (2022 CTP2 to RTM) or upgrade (2014)*

Comment: perfect! this helped in my case

Answer (score 1):

I had to right click on the file in my Downloads folder and go to Properties. I had to click the option to unblock the file in the General tab. After applying that change and re-mounting the iso, I had no issues running the tools from within the installer.